# Add links to specific words within span tag in PHP

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-match, highlighting

I have a list of words that I'd like to add a link to, I can do this fairly easily using preg_match_all and preg_replace:

```
$str = "<span class=\"cz\">Dám si jedno pivo prosím.</span> = I'll have a beer please.";

preg_match_all('/[a-zťúůýžáčďéěíňóřš]+/i',$str,$matches);
$matches = array_unique($matches[0]);

foreach ($matches as $match) {
    if(!empty($words[$match])) {
        $str = preg_replace("/(^|[^\w]){1}(".preg_quote($match,"/").")($|[^\w]){1}/i", '\\1<a href="#">\\2</a>\\3', $str);
    }
}

echo $str;
```

What I'd like to do is restrict the linking to only within the span tag.

My brain is all regex-ed out, so any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Darren.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
preg_match_all('/[a-zťúůýžáčďéěíňóřš]+(?=\s*?</span>)/i',$str,$matches);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/( *<SPAN*>)([^<]*)(<\/SPAN>)/i
```

I think something like this should work, but will break if you have other tags inside your SPAN. I'd advise you to use the DOM functions instead.